# curl/wget does not resolve a URL same as a browser when redirected

Tags: curl, wget, gitweb

How do I get the correct redirected URL by curl/wget?

Target URL:

- https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=kernel/msm-3.18.git;a=commit;h=430f3805c82634a3cb969d83acc4fc4c0ee6af27
- You need to escape `;` (semi-colon) to `%3B` when passing curl/wget

A browser, like Chrome/FireFox, resolves the above target URL to the following URL which includes `commit` and this is expected result.

- https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la//kernel/msm-3.18/commit/?id=430f3805c82634a3cb969d83acc4fc4c0ee6af27

However, both curl and wget resolve the target URL to the following URL which includes `tree` and this is NOT expected behavior.

- https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la//kernel/msm-3.18/tree/?id=430f3805c82634a3cb969d83acc4fc4c0ee6af27

The deference of redirected URL is including `commit` or `tree`, and it might be a gitweb issue instead of curl/wget.
How do I get the correct redirected URL by curl/wget?
To change a User-Agent is helpless. Any ideas?
My curl command is as follows:

```
$ curl -v -L -o output.html \
https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=kernel/msm-3.18.git%3Ba=commit%3Bh=430f3805c82634a3cb969d83acc4fc4c0ee6af27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the issue is that you need to url encode the `/` that is part of the project name.  Encoding the `;` with `%3B` broke things for me.

Also, because the URL contains `;`, you need to quote it since this is a command separator.

In the query string, the `p=kernel/msm-3.18` should be `p=kernel%2fmsm-3.18`

I was able to make the following two cURL commands work:

```
curl -v -L -o output.html \
'https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=kernel%2fmsm-3.18.git;a=commit;h=430f3805c82634a3cb969d83acc4fc4c0ee6af27'
```

Or simply,

```
curl -v -L -o output.html \
'https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=kernel/msm-3.18.git;a=commit;h=430f3805c82634a3cb969d83acc4fc4c0ee6af27'
```

This might be because the software reads the raw parameters and does not decode %3B and expects a semi-colon in the query string.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It worked, thank you. Now make sense, semi-colon is parsed as a command separator not a URL parameter.